# FFmpeg - operation not permitted

Tags: php, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, ffprobe

I have problem only this HLS url:
http://178.134.47.138:8089/hls/live.m3u8
Other url works fine

Here is my issue:

```
ffprobe http://178.134.47.138:8089/hls/live.m3u8 -loglevel debug

ffprobe version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[NULL @ 0x55705e11ef00] Opening 'http://178.134.47.138:8089/hls/live.m3u8' for reading
[http @ 0x55705e11f980] Setting default whitelist 'http,https,tls,rtp,tcp,udp,crypto,httpproxy'
[tcp @ 0x55705e121780] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 0x55705e121780] Address 178.134.47.138 port 8089
[tcp @ 0x55705e121780] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 0x55705e121780] Address 178.134.47.138 port 8089
[tcp @ 0x55705e121780] Starting connection attempt to 178.134.47.138 port 8089
[tcp @ 0x55705e121780] Successfully connected to 178.134.47.138 port 8089
[http @ 0x55705e11f980] request: GET /hls/live.m3u8 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Lavf/58.29.100
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: close
Host: 178.134.47.138:8089
Icy-MetaData: 1


http://178.134.47.138:8089/hls/live.m3u8: Operation not permitted
```

I tried different FFmpeg versions but no luck
I'm out of ideas, how can i continue debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking/resetting the permissions for your paths?
(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu etc...)

Just try to set the owner of the directories to the user, who needs access permissions.
If you try to access the files using a web server, it should be something like 'apache' or 'www-data' depending on the OS you are using, using the command 'sudo chown -R USERGROUP:USER /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'.
Now execute 'sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' grant write permissions to the owner you set in the command before.
**You might wanna use different permissions, than I suggested. I maybe have to less information about your use-case etc. to suggest the best permissions.
In that case Google might be your friend**

Another (really unsecure) command would be 'sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' which grants read and write permissions to all users. It's the best you just use this command for testing only.

Just try to apply these commands for all the directories you want to access using your program.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I already searched this problem several times but there is no suitable result for my case. I think this is not permission issue because other hls links works fine.